$\forall a,b \in K[[x]]: a | b \implies v(a) \leq v(b)$ where $v$ is the valuation
The valuation of a power series is the smallest index $i$ of the coefficients $a_i$ so that $a_i \ne 0$.
Since $a|b$ there exists a $c\in K[[x]]$ so that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$$
By the Cauchy product the LHS is equal to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{r=0}^n a_r c_{n-r}$ so we get the equality
$$\sum_{r=0}^n a_r c_{n-r}=b_nx^n$$
Is this correct? Now I need to show that $v(a)\leq v(b)$. One might start the sum on the LHS at $r=v_a$ where $v_a$ is the valuation of $a$ because all coefficients before are $0$.
However, I haven't found a way to continue the proof. Thanks for any help!

That does not define a validation in $K[[x]]$. Are you sure that's the definition?

In my script it's called "valuation". It should be the same as the order of a formal power series. Edit: Ah, I saw the mistake. I edited the definition.

Use \ne to get $\ne$ in MathJax

Note that for $n< v(a)$, we have $\sum_{r=0}^n a_r c_{n-r}= 0$ (because all the $a_r$ are zero), and therefore $b_n = 0$. This means the first possible non-zero coefficient of $b$ is $b_{v(a)}$, finishing your proof.

Perfect, thanks!
